# Current ExecJS runtime does't support ES6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, ruby-on-rails-5, rake, execjs

`rake assets:precompile` for my rails project throws below error:

> rake aborted!
>   Current ExecJS runtime does't support ES6. Please install latest Node.js.

Below is the environment information:

```
rails -v
Rails 5.0.7

ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]

node -v
v6.11.1
```

I tried reinstalling all my gems. But still, the error comes. OS is RHEL.

Comment: have you installed node.js already, which command you used. It's required to compile the Js code

Comment: No we did not install node js. It came by default in the OS offering. OS is RHEL 7.2

Answer (score 19):

i had the same problem after upgrading autoprefixer-rails to Version 9.0.0. i fixed it by setting autoprefixer-rails to a pre 9 version:

```
gem 'autoprefixer-rails', '8.6.5'
```

in my Gemfile

Comment: Same problem and solution using Rails 4.2

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar problem after upgrading to Rails 5.2

The solution for me was to add this line

```
 # make the ExecJs use NodeJs
 ENV['EXECJS_RUNTIME'] = 'Node'
```

In this file

> config/boot.rb

Then restart the rails server

Comment: Thanks Quy, I am glad I could help :)

Answer (score 7):

Replace `therubyracer` by `mini_racer` in `Gemfile`:

```
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby
```

And then:

```
$ bundle install
```

Answer (score 5):

There's been a similar issue opened in the Autoprefixer-rails gem regarding this error, but it was thrown from an ActionView Template. keep an eye out for a response from the contributor:

https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer-rails/issues/137

Answer (score -2):

Installing NodeJS solved my problem.

Comment: This is not an answer, please consider leaving a comment instead.